# Use of containble behaviour in cakephp?

Tags: cakephp, containable

I am having three tables category, subcategory and subsubcategory.
Now category table contain fields as id,name
subcategory table contain fields as id, category_id and name
and subsubcategory table contain fields as id, subcategory_id and name

now subsubcategory view/index showing columns as name,subcategory_name
but i want to display category_name also in my subsubcategory index page

I have used containable behaviour to associate two tables as category and subsubcategory

Here is my code:--

subsubcategoriescontroller:

```
$contain =array(
'Subcategory'=> array(
    'Category' =>array(
        'fields' => array('id', 'name')
           )
     ));
     $this->Subsubcategory->find('all',array('contain' => $contain));
```

appmodel:

public $actsAs = array("Containable");
still my subsubcategory page not showing expected results.
what will i do?

Comment: What is your find result showing and what are you expecting?

Comment: Specify the fields name in the `Subcategory` block inside the containable behavior. One more thing, you want to manage category at three level? if yes then you can manage it form one table categories(with parent_id). there is no need to created other tables for it.

Comment: i have used fields section in subcategory block also but no result here is my code  $contain =array(
                        'Subcategory'=> array(
                            'fields' => array('id', 'name')
                            ),
                                'Subsubcategory' =>array(
                                    'fields' => array('id', 'name')
                                )
                );

Comment: On a side note, why all these tables/models? Why not using nested data? http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#model-find-threaded | http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/tree.html

Comment: add `'recursive' => 2` after contain with find condition.

Comment: still no result  here is i have changed   $this->Subsubcategory->find('all',array('contain' => $contain,'recursive'=>2));

Answer (score 0):

Have you got the correct relationships set up in your models?

```
class Category extends AppModel {

    public $hasMany = array('Subcategory');
}

class Subcategory extends AppModel {

    public $belongsTo = array('Category');
    public $hasMany = array('Subsubcategory');
}

class Subsubcategory extends AppModel {

    public $belongsTo = array('Subcategory');
}
```

Comment: Yes BadHorsie, Here i got correct relationship set in my models same as above. can you please tell me how i show relationship between category and subsubcategory tables. i mean i want to fetch category name column in my subsubcategory index page but it is giving me an error as category model is not associated with subsubcategory